# LinkedIn RSS Feed within a Magento Enterprise 1.11 Store

Tags: php, api, magento, linkedin-api

I have a client that wants to have a feed of there companies linkedin activity on their homepage (a Magento Enterprice store). I'm not finding an RSS subscribe or anything in the API allowing this query. Anyone know differently or have another idea/approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has no built in functionality to read feeds -- it can only produce them. At least I never found any ready function section that can be of use.

There are alot of Free and Paid extensions where you can get this functionality:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=rss+reader&pl=0

Also if you'd like to code your own (although I see no point as there are free and working extensions, you can write one yourself starting from Zend Feed Reader:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.reader.html

Answer (score 0):

OR, it could be under

`System > Configuration > [CATALOG] RSS Feeds`

And also

In: `app/design/frontend/default/*template/callouts`

Add:

```
<?php
    $channel = new Zend_Feed_Rss(’http://www.yourfeed.com/news/feed’);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($channel as $item) {}
        if ($i<3){
           echo $item->get_date(’j F Y’) .'<br />';
           echo '<p>'. $item->title .'<br />';
           echo '<a href="'. $item->link .'">Read post »</a></p>';
        }
    $i++;
    }
?>
```